# Set operations (union and intersection) on simple polygons in 2D

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I am looking for an algorithm for **union** and **intersection** operations on simple polygons in 2D.

Every polygon in my application is:

- defined by a set of points (point is defined by *x* and *y* coordinates),
- convex or concave (non-convex),
- **not** self-intersecting,
- **without** holes.

---

I met two approaches. The first is algorithm that indicates intersection points as *entry* or *exit*.

- By K. Hormann and G. Greiner [ http://www.inf.usi.ch/hormann/papers/Greiner.1998.ECO.pdf ].
- I very like this approache, but there is problem with degeneracies (shared edges, touching verticies).

  - I also read solution for degeneracies: [ http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.3376.pdf ]. But I think that this solution returns wrong result for situations like this:
    [image]

The second algorithm divides edges at intersection points and then select the "right" edges for selected operation.

- By F. Martinéz et al. [ http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~vbz/cs230papers/martinez_boolean.pdf ].
- But this algorithm returns one polygon instead two triangles for this situation (operation: *intersection*, point *F* lies on edge *AB*):

[image]

---

Can you please refer me to another approache? (Polygons usually have a little edges, so efficiency is not in the first place.)

I would like to use some **algorithm** instead existing library.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following approach: for every vertex of a polygon, decide *once for all* if it is inside or outside the other polygon. The intersections points between edges tell you where the "insideness" state changes, and this allows you to delimit the fragments of both polygon outlines that you need to reassemble (for instance Out(P, Q) and Out(Q, P) are the fragments for the union, while In(P, Q) and In(Q, P) are those for the intersection).

Now to achieve good robustness at a little cost, use a coherence principle: the number of intersections along an edge must have a parity compatible with the insideness at both endoints. For instance, when joining an inside vertex to an outside vertex, you must find an odd number of intersections.

When you observe a deviation from this rule, modify the parity of the number of intersections. This can be done by discarding an intersection, or by duplicating one.

This measure will not avoid unwanted effects like very close edges not merging or microscopic intersections, but it will avoid catastrophic anomalies. It will work even with poor insideness tests or inaccurate intersection function.